# Cocoa : How to make multiline NSTextField?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

How to make multiline NSTextField? **UPDATE:** I've found in IB special type of NSTextField called "Wrapped Text Field". It is multiline but when I want get a newline I have to press Ctrl+Enter. But I want to press only Enter to get a newline. How can I do it?

Comment: You can't just use an NSTextView? It is a multiline text field.

Comment: For another solution with auto constraints you can see my answer. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/48705158/7677598](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48705158/7677598)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no way to specify this behavior solely in Interface Builder. You can do it with a delegate message as described in this tech note [QA1454](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1454/_index.html).

Here is the example delegate message from the tech note:

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl*)control textView:(NSTextView*)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector
{
    BOOL result = NO;

    if (commandSelector == @selector(insertNewline:))
    {
        // new line action:
        // always insert a line-break character and don’t cause the receiver to end editing
        [textView insertNewlineIgnoringFieldEditor:self];
        result = YES;
    }
    else if (commandSelector == @selector(insertTab:))
    {
        // tab action:
        // always insert a tab character and don’t cause the receiver to end editing
        [textView insertTabIgnoringFieldEditor:self];
        result = YES;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `NSTextView`, its a multiline `NSTextField` sorta, it is a subclass of `NSText` correct my if I am wrong. The `NSTextView` has an `NSTextStorage`, which is a  subclass of `NSAttributedString`. You need to give it an `NSAttributedString` object instead of a `NSString` to fill its contents as it can display colors etc.

```
[[yourTextView textStorage] setAttributedString:attrStr];
```

Answer (score 0):

The same answer as Jon Steinmetz but for Swift:

```swift
func control(_ control: NSControl, textView: NSTextView, doCommandBy commandSelector: Selector) -> Bool {
        if commandSelector == #selector(NSControl.insertNewline)
        {
            // new line action:
            // always insert a line-break character and don’t cause the receiver to end editing
            textView.insertNewlineIgnoringFieldEditor(self)
            return true
        }
        else if commandSelector == #selector(NSControl.insertTab)
        {
            // tab action:
            // always insert a tab character and don’t cause the receiver to end editing
            textView.insertTabIgnoringFieldEditor(self)
            return true
        }

        return false
    }
```

The delegate protocol I set up was `NSTextFieldDelegate`