# Growing NSTableView Row Height

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstextview

I have a view-based NSTableView in a MacOSX app that structures data nicely. I would like to implement the NSTableView to have row heights which grow with the content of the data entered into one of the NSTextViews. I've subclassed an NSTextView to "grow" with the user text but the issue is that having the field embedded in the TableView causes the field to be clipped.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to go about implementing a growing row size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement `-tableView:heightOfRow:` in your table view delegate and return the appropriate height for the row. Furthermore, you need to monitor the text views for changes in their height and call `-noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:` on the table view when any of them changes. To monitor the height of the text views, it should suffice to observe the `NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification` that they will post.

(If you're using auto layout generally in your UI, I think you will have to leave the text views with `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on, place them manually, and set their autoresizing masks as appropriate. Then, you would avoid setting any other constraints on them. This is because you need the frame to be set by the text layout manager but not by auto layout.)

Comment: Thanks ken, that's a huge help. I have implemented -tableView:heightOfRow: but I am having trouble with the monitoring of the text views. Playing around with the autoLayout features in IB has given me the expanding textView I was after (thanks for that - a much cleaner solution than I originally had) but I'm having issues still with the monitoring of the text view. Can you elaborate a little more on the use of noteHeighOfRowsWithIndexesChanged: and NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification?

Comment: What aspect is giving you trouble? Each time you add a text view to the table, you add your controller object as an observer of the `NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification` to the `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` with the text view at the posting "object". Then, in your notification-handling code, you look up which row corresponds to the view whose frame changed (the `object` of the notification) using `-[NSTableView rowForView:]`. Then you invoke `-noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:` on the table view, passing an index set containing the row index. Stop observing when you remove the view.

Comment: Okay, I don't think I'm understanding this correctly. I implemented -noteHeightofRowsWithIndexesChanged: but it does not seem to be getting called. Do I need to initialise NSNotificationCentre in my AppDelegate?

Comment: You don't implement `-noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:`. That's a method on `NSTableView`. You **call** that method when you need to tell the table view that the height of some rows has changed, so that it will know to ask your delegate for the new height.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ken. I'll continue to have a play with it and see if I can work it out.

Comment: I included the following code in windowControllerDidLoadNib `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(testMethod) name:NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification object:nil];` Whenever the NSTextField changes the notification is sent and triggers testMethod. It appears though that multiple notifications are being sent. I assume this is because there are a number of NSView frame changes that occur. How do I specify that I want NSNotificationCentre to listen only for the changes to the textView in my table?

Comment: You pass the text view for the `object` parameter, where you're currently passing `nil`. Also, you should generally use a method which takes a single parameter of type `NSNotification*` for your observation method. Assuming you have more than one text view in your table, you'll need that notification object to determine which has changed size. Lastly, you probably want to track the last known height of each text view and, when you get the notification, compare that with the new height. Only call `-noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:` if the height actually changed.

Comment: I am now understanding the NSNotificationCenter calls, but how do I determine the object (instead of being nil) if I don't know what the object name is? For instance, the NSTextFields will be created at runtime and dependant on for example the number of rows in the TableView. Is there a general object name that I pass to the NsNotificationCenter or am I completely misunderstanding the object parameter?

Comment: If you pass `nil`, you're effectively requesting to observe the notification from any and all views! That's not a good idea. You should add the observation at the point that the text view is added to the outline view. For example, add it in `-outlineView:didAddRowView:forRow:` and remove it in `-outlineView:didRemoveRowView:forRow:`.

Comment: What exactly should I specify as the object parameter if the text field is being created at design time in InterfaceBuilder?

Comment: Is it a text *view* or a text *field*. You've said both. They're not the same. Anyway, if the text view is part of a table cell view, then you only design the prototype in IB. In any case, you can create an outlet and connect it in IB to get a reference to the text view at the time it is added to the outline view. Just be sure to put the outlet on the relevant object. For a text view inside a table cell view, that would be the table cell view, since there's a separate one per cell. You could use a subclass of `NSTableCellView` that has a `textView` outlet (or use the `textField` if it is).

Comment: That's awesome. I pretty much got it working. Thanks Ken. I was originally using the textView but for simplicity changed to the textField. I have the textField now communicating with my delegate, but for some reason the Notification Center keeps getting called numerous times. I'm not quite sure why that is. You have been so much help though - it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to implement this in Swift 3 (with the help of [this](https://bitsandsketches.com/nstableview/2017/02/13/table-view-multiline-textfield.html) great tip and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611292/cocoa-how-to-make-multiline-nstextfield#5613225) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32332743/372347) SO answer):

[image]

Make sure the table view cell in the `NSTableView` has a delegate connection to your subclass/view controller which adopts the `NSTextFieldDelegate` protocol.

Also give it these constraints to make sure it resizes according to the height of the row:

[image]

In the delegate use this code:

```
var editedString: String? = nil
var textCellForHeight: NSTextFieldCell = NSTextFieldCell.init()

func control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldBeginEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool {
    editedString = fieldEditor.string ?? ""
    return true
}

func control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldEndEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool {
    editedString = nil
    return true
}   

 func control(_ control: NSControl, textView: NSTextView, doCommandBy commandSelector: Selector) -> Bool {
    if commandSelector == #selector(insertNewline(_:)) {
         textView.insertNewlineIgnoringFieldEditor(self)
         editedString = textView.string ?? ""
         //The NSAnimationContext lines get rid of the animation that normally happens when the height changes
         NSAnimationContext.beginGrouping()
         NSAnimationContext.current().duration = 0
         myTableView.noteHeightOfRows(withIndexesChanged: IndexSet.init(integer: selected))
         NSAnimationContext.endGrouping()
         myTable.needsDisplay = true
         return true
    }
    return false
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if let temp = editedString { //we know it’s currently being edited if it’s not nil
        textCellForHeight.stringValue = temp
        //in my case, there was a specific table column that I knew would be edited
        //you might need to decide on the column width another way.
        let column = myTable.tableColumns[myTable.column(withIdentifier: “TheColumnThatsBeingEdited”)]
        let frame: NSRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, column.width, CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        return textCellForHeight.cellSize(forBounds: frame).height
    }
  return yourStandardHeightCGFloat
}
```